# How resolve all actual types of an implementation class relative to a generic class or interface in java?

Tags: java, oop, generics

I'm trying to resolve all actual types of an implementation class relative to a generic class or interface.

I have written an `ActualTypeArgumentsResolver` for this, but it only works when the TypeName remains consistent. I want to ignore the `TypeName` and get all the actual types.
How can I achieve this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
@Test
public void testIndirectlyExtendedGenericSuperclassWithDiffTypeName() {

    abstract class AbstractClass3<AAA, BBB, CCC> { }

    abstract class AbstractClass2<AA, BB, CC> extends AbstractClass3<CC, Map, BB> { }

    abstract class AbstractClass1<A, B> extends AbstractClass2<Long, A, Boolean> { }

    class Impl extends AbstractClass1<String, Integer> {}

    Type[] arr = ActualTypeArgumentsResolver.resolve(Impl.class, AbstractClass3.class);

    Assert.assertTrue(arr.length == 3);
    Assert.assertEquals(arr[0], Boolean.class);
    Assert.assertEquals(arr[1], Map.class);
    Assert.assertEquals(arr[2], String.class);
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure Guava can do this out of the box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Guava](https://github.com/google/guava)'s `TypeToken` supports this. Use the `getSupertype` method on a `TypeToken` representing `Impl` to get the parameterised version of `AbstractClass3` with all the actual type parameters.

```
var token = TypeToken.of(Impl.class);
var supertype = token.getSupertype(AbstractClass3.class).getType();
var typeArgs = ((ParameterizedType)supertype).getActualTypeArguments();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(typeArgs));
// output: 
// [class java.lang.Boolean, interface java.util.Map, class java.lang.String]
```